# How does the spin of a particle vary if it is measured several times?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, quantum-measurements

I have three questions about 3 successive measurements of the spin of an electron. 
In the first measurement the spin is always measured to be +1/2 on the z-axis. Measurement 2 and measurement 3 are done several seconds after the first measurement. I assume that there is no interaction with other particles during this period of time.

Question 1: Measurement 2 is done on the z-axis. The spin is found to be +1/2 as in the first measurement because the wavefunction of the electron has already been collapsed. Measurement 3 is done on the x-axis; will it yield zero value?

Question 2: Measurement 2 is done on the x-axis; it will yield zero value (correct?). Measurement 3 is done on the z-axis again; will it still yield spin +1/2?

Question 3: Mesurement 2 and 3 are made on the x-axis. Will both measurements yield a zero spin value?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment

Answer (score 2):

A measurement of spin on a spin $1/2$ particle in any direction can only yield either $1/2$ or $-1/2$ because the eigenvalues of the spin operator in any direction are only those two. Since $0$ is not an eigenvalue of the spin operator (in any direction) no measurement of spin on a spin $1/2$ particle can ever yield $0$.

Now, if perform a measurement of spin in the $x$ direction after the spin had been prepared in $+1/2$ spin state in the $z$ direction then there is a $50\%$ probability for each possible outcome (either $1/2$ or $-1/2$) of the measurement of spin in the $x$ direction because an eigenstate of spin in $z$ direction is a superposition of the eigenstates of spin in $x$ direction with each eigenstate contributing to the superposition with coefficients of equal magnitude.

Once you've done the measurement of spin in $x$ direction, the particle is in an eigenstate of spin in $x$ direction. Now, again, each eigenstate of spin in $x$ direction is a superposition of the eigenstates of spin in $z$ direction with each eigenstate contributing to the superposition with coefficients of equal magnitude. Thus, if you now perform the measurement of spin in $z$ direction, it'll give either of the possible outcomes (either $1/2$ or $-1/2$) with a $50\%$ probability.

The important point is that you started with a known $+1/2$ spin state in $z$ direction but a measurement of spin in $x$ direction made it so that when you again measure the spin in $z$ direction it can come out either way. This means that the measurement of spin in $x$ direction destroyed the property of the state that it was an eigenstate of the spin in $z$ direction. This is a generic feature of measurements of observables that don't commute and can't be simultaneously measured. As pointed out in the comments, see, the sequential Stern Gerlach experiments.

Comment: I agree, thanks a lot. I got the erroneous conclusions mainly because I didn't take into account the Uncertainty Princple. Sorry about that. The Stern-Gerlach experiments speak a clear language.